# Minecraft Spigot Plugin coding, having issue with Player.sendMessage

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am getting the following error on Eclipse Java Mars while coding a simple Minecraft 1.10 test plugin: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendMessage(String) from the type CommandSender." This is in a separate class just for commands, aside from the main class. Here is the entire class:

```
package io.github.ultraMLGcode.TestPlugin;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class TestPluginCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor {

   public TestPlugin plugin;

   public TestPluginCommandExecutor(TestPlugin instance) {
       plugin = instance;
   }


 public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("basic") && sender instanceof Player) { //If the player typed /basic then do the following...

      if (sender instanceof Player) {
          Player player = (Player) sender;
          //do something
          Player.sendMessage("Hello, it is a nice day, isn't it?");
      } else {
          sender.sendMessage("You must be a player!");
      }

        //doSomething
        return true;
    }
      return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the minecraft api, but i think this can helps:

Change this line:

```
Player.sendMessage("Hello, it is a nice day, isn't it?");
```

to this line

```
player.sendMessage("Hello, it is a nice day, isn't it?");
```

I think "sendMessage" is a non static method.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, and it would normally fix it probably, except that in Eclipse with the Minecraft/Spigot api, it just changes the error symbol to a red X instead of a lightbulb with an X over it. Don't really know what this is. I don't believe any of this would be an issue if it was in my main class, but I want a separate class for my commands to practice for making a big plugin.

Comment: Wait, sorry, I think you're actually right, but the issue is still persisting. I looked at my old plugin.

Comment: Sorry for making so many comments, but it seems that when I saved it, it went away. Thanks so much for your help! I'm dumb!